# Raspberry Pi and Python (TKinter and Omxplayer)

Tags: python, audio, tkinter, raspberry-pi, alarm

we made an alarm clock program in python that uses TKinter to display the word "ALARM" when the current time equals the alarm time set by the user. Now we're trying to add an alarm sound to the program, so a sound will play when the current time reaches the alarm time set.
For some weird reason when the current time reaches the alarm time the alarm sound is opened and played about 7 times all at once and then exits.
We've tried a few different things to get it to just play the sound file once but nothing has worked. Do you guys have any suggestions at all? I can post more specific information/screenshots if need be. :)

Code so far:

```
import time
import subprocess

#GUI Setup
from Tkinter import *
alarm_window = Tk()
alarm_window.configure(bg = 'lightblue')
alarm_window.title('Alarm Clock!')

display = Label(alarm_window, font = ('Arial', 25), bg = 'lightblue', width = 13, height = 1, borderwidth = 2)
display.grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 6)

current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

def refresh_time():
    global current_time
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    if current_time == times.get():
        alarm_window.configure(bg='red')
        timelabel.configure(bg='red')
        alarmdisplay = Label(alarm_window, font = ('Arial', 25), text = 'ALARM', bg='red', width = 13, height = 1, borderwidth = 2,)
        alarmdisplay.grid(row = 2, column = 1, columnspan = 6)

        playProcess = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '/home/pi/Digital Alarm.mp3?dl=0'])

    display.config(text=current_time)
    display.after(10, refresh_time)

timelabel = Label(alarm_window, text = 'Enter H:M:S', bg = 'lightblue')
timelabel.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
times = Entry(alarm_window, width = 10, bg = 'lightgrey', justify = CENTER)
times.grid(row = 2, column = 2, columnspan = 5)

times.focus()

refresh_time()
alarm_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: why are you polling every 10 ms when you know the time will only ever chance once per second?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know `omxplayer`, but if it quits after playing the sound, you could simply wait for it to finish like:

```
playProcess = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '/home/pi/Digital Alarm.mp3?dl=0'])
playProcess.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :)
I tried that and it ran the playProcess once thankfully, except no sound actually played.